# Lookup Values in Named List to Replace in another Named List in R

Tags: r, list, functional-programming, dplyr, named

I have a list of coded answers to a survey, along with a codex which has each possible coded answer to a particular question in said survey with the actual answer stored with it. The data is set up as a list, which is built something like this for context:

```
mylist=list(a=list(AA="Yes",AB="No",AC="Maybe"),b=list(BA="Yes",BB="No",BC="Maybe"))
myanswers<-list(a="AA",b="BC")
```

So currently the data looks like:

```
myanswers
$a
[1] "AA"

$b
[1] "BC"
```

but I would like

```
myanswers
$a
[1] "Yes"

$b
[1] "Maybe"
```

I have tried using different lapply methods but have not been able to get those to work. Also, the indexes do not always line up, so trying a for loop has not garnered the best results either.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with base R and the `mapply` function assuming the lists are in the same order

```
mapply(function(a,b) a[b], mylist, myanswers)
```

of if that's not the case, you can `Map` over the names

```
Map(function(x) {
    mylist[[x]][[myanswers[[x]]]]
}, names(myanswers))
```

Comment: This would work, but some of the elements in "myanswers" are not in "mylist"
, so the program breaks and says the subscript is out of bounds

Comment: What behavior do you want in that case? It's easier to help when the reproducible example captures the different cases you wish to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Another option where you first create a lookup table

```
(lookup <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, stack)))
#    values ind
#a.1    Yes  AA
#a.2     No  AB
#a.3  Maybe  AC
#b.1    Yes  BA
#b.2     No  BB
#b.3  Maybe  BC
```

And then use `lapply` and `match` for the replacement

```
lapply(myanswers, function(x) lookup$values[match(x, lookup$ind)])
#$a
#[1] "Yes"
#
#$b
#[1] "Maybe"
```